# What are your favorite menulets (or Menu Extras as Apple calls them)?

Tags: menu-bar

Yes, I know, it's another list, but here goes:

What is your favorite menulet and what is it used for?

- Please one post one menulet per answer.
- Add a link to the developer's website, if possible.
- Duplicate answers should be flagged for deletion, so do check or edit an existing entry rather than adding a second answer for the same software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/)

MenuMeters is a free application that displays CPU usage, memory usage, network up/down, and disk write/read.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

## [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/)

Caffeine is a tiny program that puts an icon in the right side of your menu bar. Click it to prevent your Mac from automatically going to sleep, dimming the screen or starting screen savers. Click it again to go back. Right-click (or ⌘-click) the icon to show the menu.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

## [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)

by Bjango is definitely my favorite. Monitor CPU, memory, disk usage & activity, network, temp sensors, battery, and customize the date & time format. Each of these items also has a customizable drop down menu with more details.

[image: iStat Menus preferences]

[image: iStat Menus in menubar]

[image: iStat Menus memory monitor]

Comment: Agreed, one of the best software purchases I've made

Comment: Sorry for the following advertisement, but I was hesitant to buy the family pack for my Macs but today there's a promo [iStat Menus Family Pack (5 Users) 3.19](http://www.mupromo.com/?ref=7193) for 12$ instead of 24$; so I grabbed it - don't know if it's only valid for version 3.19 - actually this would make me quite angry !

Comment: Their free Dashboard app is good, too.

Answer (score 4):

## [Fantastical](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fantastical/id435003921?mt=12) ($15)

[image]

Fantastical is awesome for quickly creating new calendar events and for seeing what's coming up.  It's got some pretty smart natural language recognition, so I can just type "Architecture Review Meeting next Thursday from 4 to 6pm in Conference Room #42", and it fills out all the fields for you.  Hit <kbd>return</kbd> and you're done!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Day-O](http://shauninman.com/archive/2011/10/20/day_o_mac_menu_bar_clock) (Free)

A tiny, dead simple app that replaces the system clock and shows a calendar when you click on it. You can also freely customize the date format.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Preferences]

Answer (score 3):

## [DashExpander](http://kapeli.com/dashexpander/)

A free text expander a là… TextExpander.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

## [InsomniaX 2.0](http://semaja2.net/archives/206) (free)

It always has been a missing feature: Disabling the sleep mode on a Apple Laptop. Who does not want to use it as a big juke-box or go warwalking?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [gfxCardStatus](http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus) (free)

gfxCardStatus is a menu bar application for OS X that allows users of dual-GPU 15” and 17” MacBook Pros to view which GPU is in use at a glance, and switch between them on-demand.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Boom](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/)

- system-wide equalizer
- boost the volume of your Mac
- boost the volume of audio files

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

## [TinyAlarm](http://plumamazing.com/mac/tinyalarm/)

It's great for setting an audible reminder.

[image: TinyAlarm screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

## [Camouflage](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camouflage/id445264274?mt=12) (USD1.99)

Great little menulet to hide all the files and folders on your desktop. Much better than letting clients see all the cruft you've accumulated.

[image: Camouflage]

Comment: Or you could get rid of that stuff on the desktop to speed up login :-)

Comment: Very true! No matter how many times i clean it up, there's always junk on there!

Answer (score 2):

## [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/)

One of the most convenient ways to assign shortcuts to running AppleScripts or shell scripts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Radium](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/radium/id413215890?mt=12)

Count on it to deliver your music, news, talk, sports, from 50 countries, in 100 languages, at the blink of an eye, with a click of a button.

- equalizer
- volume control
- add custom streams
- show current radio-show name in the menubar

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Keychain Status (included with OS X)

Lock the screen immediately if you need to step away from the computer.

In addition you can lock the keychain. Fast access to Security Prefences and Keychain Access too.

[image: image of Keuchain Status menu]

You activate this menu item by checking the *Show keychain status in menu bar* option in the preferences for **Keychain Access**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_mac.html)

Plain and simple...notifies you when you have a new email. It also integrates Google Calendar into the notifier. All-in-all it's a handy little tool.

Answer (score 0):

## [Shimo](http://www.chungwasoft.com/shimo/)

A powerful VPN client that replaces all other clients you may have (including the OSX VPN setting).

- VPN profiles based on networks
- Growl notifications
- supported protocols:

  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [HUDTube](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/hudtube-video-player/id447364036?mt=12)

And it's associated Safari or Chrome add-ons, which allow you to open a youtube video from a page into a small standalone (resizable window) which is great for hour+ long podcasts which don't have video content worthy of their own tab/window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### [Notify](http://notifyapp.com/)

An extremely lightweight mail client for your status bar. It's been abandoned, unfortunately, but it works on Lion with a few bugs and the developer has let everyone use the Pro version for free. It has tons of flexibility, and lets you preview, reply, compose, and file messages, all from a little unobtrusive icon. It supports Growl, and uses very tiny amounts of CPU and RAM.

[image][image: example of message preview]

Comment: I absolutely adore Notify.  I was heartbroken when the dev announced abandonment of the project.  I know it's a huge task, but I've gotten permission from the developer to create a Notify 2 of sorts.  I'll tell you one thing: it's going to take a while.

Comment: @sudorm-rf Good luck! Be sure to let everyone know when it comes out.